# Date Range and Specific Dates

Tags: cognito-forms

Having trouble with the Date function. I'm using the form to confirm a date range and specific dates within that range. I see that Date Range is an option but not sure how to assign Date Values and Min/Max Values.

I also want a date field that will allow users to input multiple specific dates using the calendar icon to the right of the date field.

Are these things doable?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a developer with [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

The Min/Max values for a Date field will provide a range of available dates between the dates entered. This would let you provide a range of available dates for your users, they they would not be able to select outside of. You can see this in action in the following screenshots. With a range from December 1st to December 15th.

[image]

[image]

Date outside of the range are grayed out and the end user will be unable to select them. An error message will also be displayed if a date outside of the range is entered.

We do not have a Date field that will let users enter in multiple dates. You would have to set up several Date fields in order for your users to input multiple specific dates.

Answer (score -1):

For newbies, like me, I found it under workflow > public links > allow links, from there you can set calendar availability dates for opening and closing something, like registration for an event.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).